# Save additional entity in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to save an additional entity whenever a new entity of some type is updated or persisted. I know of Envers and don't want to use it because i have a slighly other use case, to be specific: time series. Because performance matters in this case, i want to implement a solution that really satisfies my requirements. 
I know of Hibernate interceptors (e.g. extending EmptyInterceptor and overriding needed methods like onFlushDirty) and its event api (e.g. PostInsertEventListener, FlushEventListener etc).

In the first case i didn't find out yet how to get the SessionFactory inside the Interceptor, with which i would open a new, temporary session (with the connection of the current session) to save my custom time series entity.

An approach with the event api seems to be more flexible and powerful and it is quite easy to get the session via the event. However, as far i understood, i have to build maps with all properties there (at least this is what i have seen in the envers code which uses this approach), so it seems to be more work to be done.

So what is the easiest way to save another entity using JPA or Hibernate? Are i'm looking in the right direction or are there other (better or easier) ways to handle this i have overlooked so far? Are there known caveats with the mentioned approaches?

Update: To make it clearer, i want to save another entity, but not of the same type. The entity to be saved is a very simple object, which just saves two dates, a reference to the original entity and and the value of one of its attributes that is of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it, it would break too many hibernate concepts. One is that an entity is identified in both memory and database and automatically synchronized to the database transparently. You can't just create new records in a flush dirty event.

- it could happen several times in the same transaction.
- you would get problems with identification, primary keys, foreign keys...
- you would get problems with cascades. Every related entity which is cascaded should be copied as well, which makes the whole thing very complicated.
- you would get problems to load the history, because there is no explicit mapping for it.

You should consider to:

- Implement explicit versioning into your domain model. That's what I'm doing in the project I'm currently working on. Control the logic in java and get explicit access to the history.
- Avoid using an ORM and implement you high-performance solution directly in SQL. Only do this if performance would be a major issue and your domain model is absolutely trivial.

Comment: Well, maybe i have given too few details. I have considered most of your points and have a solution for most of them: E.g. I have a DAO for accessing exactly the time series entry, i have written dynamic mappings and used entity-names, so in fact there is an explicit hibernate mapping for those entities. There will be no cascade because the time series entry i will save is very simple and has no collections, it only points to the original entity and so on... So thank you for your post, but it doesn't really help me as it does not really answer my question.

Comment: So when you have these entities already in the domain model, just create instances and add them. When you want to improve performance, set them readonly (I don't know if this feature is available in java, it is in NHibernate) or add it to another (stateless) session. You don't need any hibernate events, you can do this triggered from you domain.